# How to send Json data and textbox data through jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a json collection and I want to send one textbox value to controller through jQuery ajax

```
 $('#btnsave').click(function (e) {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Asset/SaveAssociate',
        data: "{'data':'"+JSON.stringify(allVals)+"'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
         //   var gridk = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");
          //  gridk.dataSource.read();
        }
    })
})
```

and this is my textbox value

```
 var _assetid = $("#AssetId").val().trim();
```

like data: `{ json and assetid :assetid }` can I pass like this

This is my action method

```
[NoCache]
public ActionResult SaveAssociate(string data, string AssetId)
{
            JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<GetUserdata> myObjs = new List<GetUserdata>();
            myObjs = json.Deserialize<List<GetUserdata>>(data);

            for (int i = 0; i <= myObjs.Count; i++)
            {
            }

            return Content("Hai");
}
```

Comment: I want to send Json collection and textbox value parameter to action method .collection is coming but if i go like this  data:{json and assetid :assetid } assetid is not coming at action method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believed, this is what you want

```
 $('#btnsave').click(function (e) {
        debugger;

       var dataToSend={
          'data':JSON.stringify(allVals),
          'AssetId':$("#AssetId").val().trim()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Asset/SaveAssociate',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
             //   var gridk = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");
              //  gridk.dataSource.read();
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: At this point 'AssetId':$("#AssetId").val().trim() am getting value but when it comes to dataToSend.AssetId it is coming null

Comment: Can you see the AssetId value being passed in request?

Comment: Also, please show your code for Action that is suppose to accept these parameters

Comment: I guess, you have to put dataToSend inside click event, check out the updated code.

Comment: Yes but ajax is not calling Action method if i kept like this

Comment: Try now with the updated code. I believed, it should work now.